# Displaying 'heatmap' for words in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to generate something similar to this image (image taken from [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Explaining-Predictions-of-Non-Linear-Classifiers-in-Arras-Horn/9e3f3d1e1e86cc497315f78617c909ae9a485f21))
[image]

I have the list of words and list of the normalized score (let's say in 0-1) for a document. How can I create such a heatmap (each word gets a color assigned based on the score)? I have no idea where to even begin, I am not proficient with matplotlib!

PS the scores are mostly 0, it is a sparse mapping.

Comment: Does “similar to this image” imply exactly the same image looking? Is printing a colored text on the terminal an option?

Comment: The easiest way to create something similar will be creating an hmtl page where you can give a color to individual words. Matplotlib certainly isn't the most adequate tool for such images. Use python to create a simple html page and a web browser to display it. BTW, your example image is probably created just with LaTex.  At 
 ex.stackexchange.com you can find answers to many questions.

Comment: [This tex.stackexchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248632/highlight-every-occurrence-of-a-list-of-words) has a lot of pointers towards a solution. But probably somewhere will exist an even more specific package.

Comment: @FaresSalem I guess that would also be fine, I can just take a screenshot of it, but I want it to be in a 'highlighter' style, ie, I want the background to be colored, not the text specifically. JohanC 's link just colors the text and it offers less clarity in my opinion

Comment: @RedFloyd Please show some efforts in searching. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372252/add-colored-background-to-listing-with-colored-words) for example also changes the text background.

Answer (score 6):

There are many solutions for this.  Almost anything that renders highlighted text will work so long as you can access it with software (HTML, TeX/LaTex, MS Word using `python-docx`, LibreOffice, etc).  Probably the easiest, most versatile, and with the most universal deliverable is HTML.

Here's a bit of code that will, as an example, randomly highlight about 1:5 of the words with one of four preset colors.  (I assume the OP will have a better plan for choosing which words and which colors to use.)

I wrote this in Jupyter notebook because it allowed for an easy display of the output.  There are many ways to display html (which is html's main advantage), but if you don't want to use a Jupyter notebook, then leave out the `IPython` import and the `display` line.

[image]

```
import random
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

data = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."""

def highlighter(word):
    colors = ["#FF3333", "#DD9999", "#9999DD", '#3333FF']
    i = random.randint(0, 18)
    if i < len(colors):
        color =  colors[i]
        word = '<span style="background-color:' +color+ '">' +word+ '</span>'
    return word

text = ' '.join([highlighter(word) for word in data.split()])

display(HTML(text))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ChrisMorrisOrg/4450466), It works well through the terminal.
So you can iterate through the list of Scores, skip the zeros, and color the words with the corresponding indexes as you like.

[image: Output Example]

Answer (score 0):

you can easily generate this heatmap using https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

[image]